# Extract nth element from comma-delimited list with Google Sheets formula

Tags: filter, split, google-sheets-formula, match, delimited

I have a string:

> "apple12,bear23,chile,dormir45,elephant"

I'd like to use the regexextract() formula to get the nth element from this list, where n is going to be a row() in an arrayformula.  I just need the regex where I can input a number {1}, {2}, {3}, etc.

Workbook to help: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zAf41twr_JCkZ44Qo5j73WrWhXDc2KoOo3UI4RpyUI8/edit?usp=sharing

I realize this is probably possible with =SUBSTRING() as well.

Comment: Try "=INDEX(SPLIT(B4,","),0,1)"    so it will split data as an array and provide you the value of the given position. =INDEX(SPLIT(<source>,","),0,<nth position>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1, ","),, B2)
```

where B2 is value with position

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From @Dhiraj:

Try "=INDEX(SPLIT(B4,","),0,1)" so it will split data as row and provide u value of the given position. =INDEX(SPLIT(,","),0,)

Comment: This is what I used.  I forgot about SPLIT().